# SQL query for 2 different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have tables:

1. Trips: Trip_Num, Trip_Type, etc.
2. User's Trips History: Username, Trip_Num, etc.

I am doing a project in php and need to do a SQL query for a specific user (by his username) - need to know the Trip_Type for the Trip_Num in the User's Trips History table.

Attached the tables I have:

**Trips**

[image]

**User's Trips History**

[image]

Update:
I need to do count on each value in the Trip_type. I mean I want to see "on foot" - 4 occurences, "Bicycle" - 3 occurences, this is good?...........................................................................‌​ select Trips_History.*,Trips.Trip_Type, COUNT(Trip_Type) AS Trip_Type_occurrence FROM Trips History INNER JOIN Trips on Trips_History.Trip_Num = Trips.Trip_Num GROUP BY Trip_Type ORDER BY Trip_Type_occurrence DESC –

Comment: Look into this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

A simple `JOIN` will do:

```
SELECT
    th.*,
    t.Trip_Type
FROM Trip_History AS th
INNER JOIN Trips AS t
    ON t.Trip_Num = th.Trip_Num
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 select Trips_History.*,COUNT(Trips.Trip_Type) AS Trip_Type_occurrence FROM Trips_History INNER JOIN Trips on Trips_History.Trip_Num = Trips.Trip_Num  GROUP BY Trip_Type ORDER BY Trip_Type_occurrence DESC
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to do count on each value in the Trip_type. I mean I want to see "on foot" - 4 occurences, "Bicycle" - 3 occurences, this is good?............................................................................................... select Trips_History.*,Trips.Trip_Type, COUNT(`Trip_Type`) AS `Trip_Type_occurrence` FROM Trips History INNER JOIN Trips on Trips_History.Trip_Num = Trips.Trip_Num GROUP BY Trip_Type ORDER BY Trip_Type_occurrence DESC

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select t2.traveller_username,t1.Trip_Type from 
trips as t1 inner join trips_history as t2 on t1.Trip_num=t2.trip_num
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
SELECT t.Trip_Type, u.Trip_Num from trips at t 
JOIN user_trips_history ON u.Trip_Num = t.Trip_Num 
WHERE u.Traveller_Username = 'username';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
SELECT t.Trip_Type, u.Trip_Num FROM trips as t 
JOIN user_trips_history as u ON t.Trip_Num=u.Trip_Num 
WHERE u.Traveller_Username = 'USERNAME';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this -

```
SELECT users_trip_history.trip_num, trips.trip_type, COUNT(trips.trip_type) AS trip_occurences
FROM users_trip_history
INNER JOIN trips
ON users_trip_history.trip_num = trips.trip_num 
WHERE users_trip_history.traveler_username = "name"
GRUOP BY trip_num;
```